# OVRCameraRig not displaying both camera eyes in Unity player?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

Unity 5.5.2f1

I'm trying to get started with making an Oculus app, following the instructions [here](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/unity-integration-tutorial-rollaball-intro/), modifying a very simple scene I made.  However, when I disable the MainCamera and drag in the OVRCameraRig, and run it in the Editor, I still only see a single frame, not these multiple eye views like in the picture.  Player settings have "VR Supported" selected.  Do I have something not set up right with the app?  Or is the tutorial out of date or something?

Comment: did you try running it in the `Editor`?

Comment: That's exactly where I'm trying to run it.  Updated the question.

Comment: Did you try opening one of the example scenes and just running that with no modifications?

Comment: Have you checked the tick box in the Player settings that says VR Supported?

Comment: I have.  I've added that into the question now.

Comment: Next time I suggest including me in your comment like this @user650261, since I didn't see your update. Anyway look at the subtitle of your tutorial _"This section describes the steps necessary to build, load, and run a simple Unity 3D application on the Oculus Rift or Samsung Gear VR."_ Maybe try a `Oculus` only tutorial if that is your intentions.